# Error in serving cached graphql query responses

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I am newbie to service worker, I am writing a custom sw.js for my react project to support pwa. It has graphql implementation at the back-end. I have cached the responses of the graphql responses but unable to serve if user goes offline.
This is the custom sw.js snippet code :

```
if(event.request.url=== 'https://my.custombackend.com/graphql'){
              console.log('graphql request incoming!');
            return event.respondWith(
              caches.match('/graphql').then(graphqlRes=>{     //THIS LINE IS CAUSING ERROR AS sw.js is unable to retrieve such match . But in image you can see I have already cached the graphql response.
               if(graphqlRes){
                console.log(graphqlRes)
                console.log('graphql request being served from cache');
                return graphqlRes;
               }
               else return fetch(event.request).then(cacheToBe=>{
                return caches.open(dynamicCache).then(newEntry=>{
                  console.log('graphql request served! Now caching...');
                  newEntry.put(event.request.url, cacheToBe.clone());
                  return cacheToBe;
                })
              })
            }))
          }
```

Expected behavior : sw.js should fetch the required '/graphql' cached data.
Actual behavior : It doesn't recognizes that and falls back to  offline.html

image link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV3jk.png

Comment: I'm also researching the way to use SW cache with GraphQL. One key problem seem to be POST which has limited to no support. GraphQL queries use either POST payload or very long query params (GET with query params is neither efficient nor good for security).
In general I think the chance for a quick and dirty way would be to experiment with GET and queries in the query params - this will be used as a part of a cache key

Comment: another option is to go for `apollo-cache-persist` and keep cache in a localStorage - while less ideal then SW cache, still more compliant with GraphQL